# How to prevent custom dialog from closing in kendo-angularjs-scheduler control?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

How can I prevent custom dialog from closing in scheduler control in kendo ui?

I have created one demo project with kendo-angular and configured kendo`s scheduler control in that.

I have to create one custom kendo template which popup`s while double clicking on calendar date. I want to validate response when I will save values of template, if error comes from server I want to display that error on template and not want to close dialog.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
cancel: function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

to your scheduler config